# Is it possible to monitor dconf for changes?

Tags: dconf

I would like to monitor `dconf` for changes so that while I tinker with settings, applications and the like I can see what keys are changed, if any.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want real-time monitoring, you could run the `dconf watch` command in a terminal, either to monitor a specific schema path

```
dconf watch /desktop/gnome/remote-access/
```

or the whole tree

```
dconf watch /
```

which will show a running output as you change values, e.g. toggling the 'Desktop Sharing' security preference checkbox produces

```
/desktop/gnome/remote-access/notify-on-connect
  false

/desktop/gnome/remote-access/notify-on-connect
  true
```

If you just want a list of changes, you could use `dconf dump` redirected to a file to create before and after snapshots that you can then compare with `diff`.