# Where are System settings stored in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, 17.10, system-settings, gnome-shell-extension

I'm looking for the files where System settings are stored for the following preferences:

- Touchpad
- Gnome Shell Extension Preferences
- Wifi

It's for a live USB that doesn't persist any prefs. I'm just setting up a little script that restores a few basic preferences so I don't have to redo them every time I use it. It's mostly done but I was missing these few items. I  know there is a way to make persistant USB installs but it's not really needed for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

#### Touchpad

This depends on what you use to configure the touchpad. For a Synaptics touchpad, you could use the [`synclient`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=synclient) command line tool to save and restore preferences. Other preferences probably get saved somewhere in the [dconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dconf.7) database, and you can use [`gsettings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gsettings) to save and restore those.

- [Is it possible to monitor dconf for changes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/359593/158442)

Example of Editing Mouse Config using gsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false
```

#### WiFi

Network Manager settings go in `/etc/NetworkManager` (and connection setting specifically in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`). This directory requires `sudo` access to modify from the command line. The [`nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nmcli) command line tool can be used to automate configuring network connections to some extent.

#### GNOME Shell extensions

From [the GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions#Extension_Preferences):

> #### Extension Preferences
>
> Since version 3.3.5, Extensions may be configured in a consistent
>   manner using the `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` tool. To hook into it,
>   provide a simple javascript file called **prefs.js**.

It doesn't look like this is meant to be used outside of extensions, and I don't have a GNOME Shell on hand to test with, but `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` seems to be your best bet to get and set extension preferences.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll give your suggestions a try. For the gnome-extension, I had already looked through prefs.js, it's actually just the preference window as as opposed the preferences themselves. I tried to read through to see where's it's saving the preferences but I couldn't find any reference to any files or dconf (though I have to admit, js and my brains don't mix, so maybe I just missed it). Maybe I should just do a text search for the default values and change the handful of options I don't have at default.

Comment: You were right about the mouse settings, they were buried in the dconf database. I was able to change touchpad settings using:  
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false . Pretty much anything settings can be manipulated that way. I was also able to find the Wifi networks in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections as you had suggested. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, I misread your question:

The files:
- Gnome Shell Extension Preferences: ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

---

- Touchpad: Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad
- Gnome Shell Extension Preferences: https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

  - Make sure you've installed the browser plugin to enable communication between Gnome and the web page: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation
  - You can find a small button with a tool symbol next to every installed Shell Extension that has configuration options
- Wifi: Settings > Wi-Fi

  - When you've connected to a Wi-Fi Network, a cog wheel will appear in the network when shown in the "Visible Networks" overview.
  - You've got the hamburger menu in the top right corner that enables you to do some connection stuff. There you can also see all you're saved networks via "Known Wi-Fi Networks"

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply cp3o but for the touchpad/wifi, I was asking about where the preferences get saved on the ssd or hard drive and not where to find  them within the system pref app. As for the gnome-shell prefs, the location you gave me is where the extensions get installed to but not where the preferences get saved. I know this because I've transfered those files to another machine and although I have the extensions now, I don't have their preferences. Thanks for going out of your way to answer me anyway.

Comment: About the touchpad/wifi I don't quite know this by heart. For these settings I think @muru's answer is better, but he also doesn't always refer to files of course.
As for the gnome-shell extensions I've got the SomaFM extension on my machine and for this extensions I've extensively modified the config in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/. Take a look at the subdirectories because you can find some .js-files that might help. In these subdirectories you can also find the pref.js that is mentioned by muru

Comment: It seems the extension preferences are also save in dconf: /org/gnome/shell/extensions/